# Is there any way to connect local git-p4 repo to remote git repo while keeping connection with the p4 depot?

Tags: git, perforce

I'm trying to write a power-shell script to rebase all changes from a perforce depot and push them into a remote git repo I cloned using the git-p4 clone command. It looks like when I update the git config file and attempt to push to the remote git repo I made, the push fails since the files are technically not local to my machine, but are instead pointing to the remote perforce depot. Is there any way to connect my local git-p4 repo to a remote git repo while keeping connection with the p4 depot so I can still rebase as needed?

Comment: You can configure multiple [remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) in GIT if that's what you mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pull/push from multiple remote locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations)